# VS Code Error Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

### Issue Description

Error when creating and loading dotnet console application for .NET 5.0

### Steps to Reproduce

- Start VS Code under Windows 10
- Create a new dotnet project using C#

```
dotnet new console --framework net5.0
```

- Try to use IntelliSense

### Expected Behavior

Everything is working fine and C# IntelliSense is working.

### Actual Behavior

Error reported from OmniSharp Output Log.
You can build and run the project, but IntelliSense is not working.

It was working before and suddenly stopped working.

### Logs

#### OmniSharp log

### Environment information

**VSCode version**: 1.65.2
**C# Extension**: 1.24.1

See the full output log attached.

[OmniSharp output.log](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/files/8282168/OmniSharp.output.log)

```
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.2
  Commit:  839cdfb0ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Visual Studio Code Extensions

| Extension | Author | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| atlascode | atlassian | 2.10.9 |
| Bookmarks | alefragnani | 13.2.4 |
| code-spell-checker | streetsidesoftware | 2.1.7 |
| csharp | ms-dotnettools | 1.24.1 |
| data-workspace-vscode | ms-mssql | 0.1.1 |
| dotnet-test-explorer | formulahendry | 0.7.7 |
| fabric8-analytics | redhat | 0.3.5 |
| java | redhat | 1.4.0 |
| mssql | ms-mssql | 1.13.0 |
| open-lnk | EnkelDigital | 0.0.1 |
| packsharp | elsnoman | 2.3.2 |
| powershell | ms-vscode | 2021.12.0 |
| sql-database-projects-vscode | ms-mssql | 0.14.1 |
| vscode-commons | redhat | 0.0.6 |
| vscode-eslint | dbaeumer | 2.2.2 |
| vscode-fileutils | sleistner | 3.5.0 |
| vscode-html-css | ecmel | 1.11.0 |
| vscode-java-debug | vscjava | 0.38.0 |
| vscode-java-dependency | vscjava | 0.19.0 |
| vscode-java-pack | vscjava | 0.22.0 |
| vscode-java-test | vscjava | 0.34.2 |
| vscode-maven | vscjava | 0.35.1 |
| vscode-nuget-package-manager | jmrog | 1.1.6 |
| vscode-yaml | redhat | 1.5.1 |
| vscodeintellicode | VisualStudioExptTeam | 1.2.17 |
| xml | DotJoshJohnson | 2.5.1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remover `"omnisharp.path": "latest"` setting JSON file.